# How to check if record exist in respons TWIG - data in table format

Tags: php, twig

I have a multidimensional array where some objects exist and others don't. The whole data has used in page. Then I plan check it in TWIG. 
example data:

```
array:2[
  0 => Data1 {
    -id: 17
    -porodType: "1d"
    -name: "Dally promotion" 
  }
  1 => Data1 {
    -id: 34
    -porodType: "S"
    -name: "Special" 
  }    
]
```

How to check if record with porodType = "1d" exist in respons? 
How to display different message for this acction: exist(OK)/no-exist(ERROR)?

When check in TWIG:

```
{% for d in Data1 %}
    {% if d.porodType == '1d' %}
        <button class="btn">OK</button>
    {% else %}
        <button class="btn"">Error</button>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

this code result is: `<button class="btn">OK</button><button class="btn">Error</button>`

but I expected `<button class="btn">OK</button>` or `<button class="btn">ERROR</button>`

Comment: It's looping through the array, and the first bit of data returns true and therefore the OK button, but the second loop through returns false and therefore the ERROR button.

Comment: I understand it but do not know how to get the expected result

Comment: What's the name of the array variable? You are using `Data1` in which there are two elements within the array called that. I want to know the name of the array that holds these two sub-arrays.

Comment: I add only two to show example but it is more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to show one button, you'd need to keep track of an error with a flag as you can't break loops in `Twig`,

```
{% set error = false %}
{% for d in Data1 %}
    {% if d.porodType != '1d' %}
        {% set error = true %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if error %}
    <button class="btn">Error</button>
{% else %}
    <button class="btn">OK</button>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using twig's for..if..else may be simpler than the currently accepted answer:

```
{% for d in Data1 if d.porodType == "1.d" %}
<!-- show error button -->
{% else %}
<!-- show the okay button -->
{% endfor %}
```

The else clause kicks in when the loop was empty (didn't have any iterations).

See documentation of *for* tag: https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/for.html

Comment: Its simple and nice @Maerlyn

Comment: This could possibly show the error button multiple times tho

Comment: Indeed it may, it's not really specified in the question if that can happen. In that case it would need a variable, like your answer.